# CsvToBean treat string value as null

Tags: opencsv

Is there a way for CsvToBean to treat a specific string or character as null when it maps into a Bean class?

For example I have a CSV that has a quoted value of "-". I know that when creating a CsvToBean you can specify

```
.withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator)
```

which handles cases when a value is not present in CSV data. Just can't find a way to treat a character value as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No OpenCSV does not do data translation like that.   You will have to change your the setters in your bean to translate the value as you are setting it.